# Why are my Pinia store getters undefined?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to use Pinia with vue 2 and composition api.
I followed the docs to install `pinia@next`, used it with `Vue.use(PiniaPlugin)` and in the app used `Vue({ ..., pinia: createPinia() })`

When i create a store copy-pasting from docs

```
export const useStore = defineStore('main', {
  state: () => ({
    counter: 1,
  }),
  getters: {
    doubleCount: (state) => state.counter * 2,
  },
})
```

and in a component, do

```
<template>
  <p>Double count is {{ store.doubleCount }}</p>
  <p>Counter is {{ store.counter }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()

    return { store }
  },
}
</script>
```

Why is my getter `doubleCount` always `undefined` (when inspecting from setup(), or trying to use in template?
`store.counter` shows the correct value.

I'm new to both Vue and Pinia, so I must be doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the current @next -version (2.0.0-rc8) has broken getters in stores. https://github.com/posva/pinia/issues/660

Using @latest worked for me, required a subtle modification in store `defineStore` syntax (`id` prop instead of name as 1st argument)